# Plotting a chloropleth map of Australian states

Tags: r, leaflet

I plotted a dot density map of the Australian states and am now trying to plot a chloropleth map of the Australian states using the leaflet package and color each state by the count value. I have the following data frame

```
state                           count  latitude longitude
Australian Capital Territory      125     ...      ...
New South Wales                    45
Northern Territory                 75
Queensland                         12
South Australia                   245
Tasmania                         4895
Victoria                          279
```

The following is the code I used to plot the dot density map

```
leaflet(aus_state_counts) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        layerId = ~state,
        label = ~state,
        radius = ~count
      ) %>%
      fitBounds(lng1 = max(aus_state_counts$longitude) ,lat1 = max(aus_state_counts$latitude),
                lng2 = min(aus_state_counts$longitude) ,lat2 = min(aus_state_counts$latitude)
)
```

I am unsure how to plot the states on the map? Do I need additional information for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a choropleth map you will need some spatial polygon data in the form of a shape file (.shp) or GeoJSON (.geojson). Below should work.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# GeoJSON Data
states <-  read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rowanhogan/australian-states/master/states.geojson")


counts <- data.frame(state=c("Australian Capital Territory", "New South Wales", "Northern Territory", "Queensland",
                             "South Australia", "Tasmania", "Victoria"), count=c(125,45,75,12,245,4895,279))

# Join to count data
data <- states %>%
  dplyr::left_join(counts, by=c("STATE_NAME" = "state"))

# Specify choropleth colors
pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", domain = data$count)

# Plot Map
leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor=~pal(count), fillOpacity=0.8, color="white", weight=1)
```